# NDSolve WorkingPrecision

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, warning-messages

I'm trying to solve differential equations but encountered singularity problem as usual. My idea is to solve is by using higher `WorkingPrecision`, but somehow it always gives me errors

For example,

```
eqs = {51.7 ti'[tau] == qH[tau] + qS - 0.7343549132947976 (-tae + ti[tau]), 
  0 == -ti[tau] + tr[tau] - Exp[-2.655/Max[1.*10^(-9), vF[tau]]] (-ti[tau] + tv), 
  0 == qH[tau] - 1.1021142600089968` (-tr[tau] + tv) vF[tau],
  0 == vF[tau] - Max[0, 20 + 20 (20 - ti[tau])]}
vars = {ti[tau], qH[tau], tr[tau], vF[tau]}
```

The solution of the steady-state equation can be used as initial condition. Without manually setting the working precision, it runs smoothly.

```
ic = (FindRoot[eqs[[All, 2]] //. {tv -> 28, qS -> 0, tae -> -2.5 Cos[2 Pi/24 tau], tau -> 0}, Transpose[{vars /. tau -> 0, ConstantArray[RandomReal[], Length[vars]]}]] /. Rule -> Equal)
NDSolve[{eqs /. {tv -> 28, qS -> 0, tae -> -2.5 Cos[2 Pi/24 tau]}, ic}, vars, {tau, 0, 24 30}]
```

When I try to set `WorkingPrecision->10`, it gives me the error.

```
With[{eqNew = 
   SetPrecision[{eqs /. {tv -> 28, qS -> 0, 
       tae -> -2.5 Cos[2 Pi/24 tau]}, ic}, 10]}, 
 NDSolve[eqNew, vars, {tau, 0, 24 30}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]]

NDSolve::mconly: For the method NDSolve`IDA, only machine real code is available. Unable to continue with complex values or beyond floating-point exceptions.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can only use `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` for the IDA method, which is the only way to solve a DAE.  Try differentiating your algebraic equations in `eqs`. -- Side remark: Machine precision is almost 16, but without precision tracking and extra guard digits.  I'd recommend setting `WorkingPrecision` to 16 or higher, if you want higher precision.

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks for reply. This is quite a sad news to me. I struggle with NDSolve all the time. It always gives me error like singularity issues etc. Thought tune up the WorkingPrecision might help. Also appreciate your side remark.

Comment: Yeah, I was testing it out.  The piecewise nature of `Max` gives some trouble when differentiated.  I didn't solve it.

Comment: The Max function is actually only to avoid vF[tau] dropping down to 0. There might be another way to do the same thing.

Comment: When rationalizing equations, `èqs=Rationalize[ ....,0]`I don't have any problems with NDSolve, working with MMA 8.0.

Comment: With[{eqNew = Rationalize[{eqs /. {tv -> 28, qS -> 0, tae -> -2.5 Cos[2 Pi/24 tau]}, ic}, 0]}, NDSolve[eqNew, vars, {tau, 0, 24 30}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]] doesn't work for me with MMA 11.1.1

Comment: Simply drop WorkingPrecision->10

Comment: The meaning of this is try to tune up/down the working precision. Dropping it, the NDSolve will automatically work with machine precision.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the 4 equations to one differential equation with Eliminate.

```
eqs2 = Rationalize[eqs, 0]

eli1 = Eliminate[eqs2, {qH[tau], tr[tau]}]

eli2 = Rationalize[
       eli1[[1]] /. vF[tau] -> Max[0, 20 + 20 (20 - ti[tau])] /. {tv -> 28,
       qS -> 0, tae -> -2.5 Cos[2 Pi/24 tau]}, 0]

(*   0 == 7060436955/2 Cos[(\[Pi] tau)/12] - 
  59339000000 Max[0, 20 + 20 (20 - ti[tau])] + 
  59339000000 E^(-(531/(
  200 Max[1/1000000000, 20 + 20 (20 - ti[tau])])))
  Max[0, 20 + 20 (20 - ti[tau])] + 1412087391 ti[tau] + 
  2119250000 Max[0, 20 + 20 (20 - ti[tau])] ti[tau] - 
  2119250000 E^(-(531/(
  200 Max[1/1000000000, 20 + 20 (20 - ti[tau])])))
  Max[0, 20 + 20 (20 - ti[tau])] ti[tau] + 
  99413671500 Derivative[1][ti][tau]   *)

ini = Rationalize[ic[[1]], 0]

ndsol = NDSolve[eli2 && ini, ti, {tau, 0, 24 30}]
```

It workes down to `WorkingPrecision->9` with MMA 8.0

```
ndsol9 = NDSolve[eli2 && ini, ti, {tau, 0, 24 30}, 
         WorkingPrecision -> 9]
```

You then get the qH[tau], tr[tau], vF[tau] from the algebraic equations.

Comment: It's a very nice solution! It would be even nicer, if I won't have to simplify the equations with Eliminate, because what I posted here are only simplified solutions. It can be very exhausted to look up all the equations and try to find out all the simplification possibilities.